# How to stop video playback when changing a scene in Flash Action Script 3

Tags: flash, video

I am new to action script and i am having a few problems.

I have created a simple 3 scene movie in Flash CC. One of the scene have video to play. The problem is when I go to the next scene/page, the video is still playing in the background with a sound. Can anybody help me how to stop the video when changing to the next scene.?

Here is the action script I am using:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

b1.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, gob1);
function gob1 (e:MouseEvent):void {
Object(root).gotoAndStop(1,"recitation");
}

***// the scene that have video //***
b2.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, gob2);
function gob2 (e:MouseEvent):void {
Object(root).gotoAndStop(1,"tafsir");
}


b3.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, gob3);
function gob3 (e:MouseEvent):void {
Object(root).gotoAndStop(1,"about");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a netStream, then you can reference this: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d4d.html

If using netStream, just call the .pause method on the netStream instantiation.

However, I recommend the use of the Greensock video frame work, as it provides much additional functionality such as: Prioritized loading, size sampling, load time estimates, etc.. and simplified syntax for video playback functionality.

Greensock documentation can be found here: https://greensock.com/asdocs/com/greensock/loading/VideoLoader.html

Greensock download: http://greensock.com/LoaderMax-AS3

Comment: Actually im not doing this for web. Im doing for standalone application. For the video i just want it to be stop when i change the scene.

Comment: I already got the solution from this link: http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=210958